# what database choose for offline chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension.

The goal of this extension is to scrap some data on a website and then export it as CSV or Excel.

My problem is that I need to store data I find : I don't think localstorage is a suitable solution since I will need something more flexible and robust.

It looks like **Web SQL database** has been dropped.

What is the way to store and retrieve data from google extension in a database style (columns, keys)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) and it looks like it could be useful to you.